# matching the individual words from array

Tags: php

//  I am working on matching the individual words from array  $frequency 
//  to the search results from that individual word.

I don't know why this does not work

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= ($frequency); $i++) {

    echo $i;


    echo getphp_AlexVortaro ($frequency[$i]);
    echo getphp_Smartfm($frequency[$i]);
    print_r($frequency[$i]);


}
```

I get

> ```
> Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in /Users/briancarpenter/Sites/Vortoj/countplus.php
> ```
>
> on line 21

X A lot

Comment: I think you might need to show some more code in order for us to help you more efficiently. A starter would be the line numbers of the code you've already posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: (1) Arrays are 0-based, not 1-based. (2) Your conditional needs to use the [count()](http://php.net/count) function.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($frequency); $i++)
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP array subscripts start at 0, not 1. You want your loop to be

for ($i = 0; $i < count($frequency); $i++)
{
...